# getting list of indices of each value of list in a pythonic way

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `data` of values, and I want to return a dictionary mapping each value of `data` to a list of the indices where this value appears.

This can be done using this code:

```
data = np.array(data)
{val: list(np.where(data==val)[0]) for val in data}
```

but this runs in O(n^2), and this is too slow for long lists. Can an O(n) solution be coded using a "pythonic" syntax? (it can be done with creating an empty list and updating it in a loop, but I understand this is not recommended in python.)

Comment: A loop is fine.

Comment: Just loop and update it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of `lists` to achieve this in O(n):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    d[item].append(idx)
```

For example, if `data` contains the string `'abcabccbazzzqa'`:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate('abcabccbazzzqa'):
    d[item].append(idx)

>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [0, 3, 8, 13], 'q': [12], 'c': [2, 5, 6], 'b': [1, 4, 7], 'z': [9, 10, 11]})
>>> d['a']
[0, 3, 8, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
data = np.array(data)
dic = {}

for i, val in enumerate(data):
    if val in dic.keys():
        dic[val].append(i)
    else:
        dic[val]=[]
        dic[val].append(i)
```

Comment: You don't need `dic.keys()`, `val in dic` checks the keys. Also, it is better to use `dic.setdefault(val, []).append(i)` or better yet, use a `defaultdict`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: You're welcome! These will become idiomatic the more you use Python.